# How to get distinct results when I have columns with different values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables and in one of them, 'requests', I have users to whom I have sent friend requests, or I have received friend requests. In the second table I keep record of shortlisted users for myself. Now, I want to select all these users together (to whom I have requested, who have requested me, whom I have shortlisted). I am using union query for this and differenciate them on the basis of column type

```
select Distinct userid,type,status from
(
select RequestSenderId as UserId,'requestedme' as type,'1' as status from tblrequest where RequestReceiverId=@UserId 

union
select RequestReceiverId as UserId,'requestedbyme' as type,'2' as status from tblrequest where RequestSenderId=@UserId 

union
select Shortlisteduserid as UserId,'Shortlisted' as type,'0' as status from tblshortlist where userid=@UserId
)
```

The problem is I am not getting distinct userid if I have shortlisted it also, and he has sent me a request also.

Can anyone suggest ahow to get distinct userid from the result. Priority is to get the userid as requested rather than as shortlisted.

Comment: Have you tried using UNION ALL?

Comment: yes. it is giving same result

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That a particular user ID shows up in the final result set twice, and you only want it once?

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @arion i am using sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

```
select userid,type,status from
(
select Distint  RequestSenderId ,'requestedme' as type,'1' as status from tblrequest where ReceiverId=@UserId 

union ALL
select Distint  RequestReceiverId ,'requestedbyme' as type,'2' as status from tblrequest where SenderId=@UserId 

union ALL
select Distint  Shortlisteduserid ,'Shortlisted' as type,'0' as status from tblshortlist where userid=@UserId
)
```

Comment: no it is giving same results because you are not selecting destinct from the total results but from the seperate tables

Comment: @nav try with union all, i found its working in oracle with some simulated data

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? It is probably not the most efficient solution though..

```
WITH requestedMe (userid, type, status)
    AS (
        SELECT RequestSenderId AS UserId,'requestedme' AS type,'1' AS status 
        FROM tblrequest 
        WHERE ReceiverId=@UserId)
    requestedByMe (userid, type, status)
    AS (
        SELECT RequestReceiverId AS UserId,'requestedbyme' AS type,'2' AS status 
        FROM tblrequest 
        WHERE SenderId=@UserId
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM requestedMe
                WHERE requestedMe.userid = tblrequest.RequestReceiverId))
    shortListed (userid, type, status)
    AS (
        SELECT Shortlisteduserid AS UserId,'Shortlisted' AS type,'0' AS status 
        FROM tblshortlist 
        WHERE userid=@UserId
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM requestedMe
                WHERE requestedMe.userid = tblshortlist.Shortlisteduserid)
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM requestedByMe
                WHERE requestedByMe.userid = tblshortlist.Shortlisteduserid))
SELECT userid, type, status
FROM requestedMe
UNION
SELECT userid, type, status
FROM requestedByMe
UNION
SELECT userid, type, status
FROM shortListed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ranking function (ROW_NUMBER or DENSE_RANK) to prioritise results.

```
SELECT UserId, Type, Status
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, Type, Status
    , Priority = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Type DESC)
    FROM (
        SELECT ReceiverId, RequestSenderId, 'requestedme', 1 FROM tblRequest
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SenderId, RequestReceiverId, 'requestedbyme', 2 FROM tblRequest
        UNION ALL
        SELECT UserId, Shortlisteduserid ,'Shortlisted', 0 FROM tblShortlist
    ) U (FilterUserId, UserId, Type, Status)
    WHERE FilterUserId = @UserId
) R
WHERE Priority = 1
```